# Correct ZFS-8000-4J non-destructively?

Tags: zfs

I'm running a raidz2 pool on Linux Mint 19.x.  I'm seeing the following in the pool status:

david@Media:~$ zpool status
  pool: data
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: resilvered 1.27T in 8h15m with 0 errors on Tue Nov 26 09:53:36 2019
config:

```
NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
data                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz2-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
    sdb                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdc                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdd                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    sde                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    10841317365380570418  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdf1
    sdh                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdi                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdj                   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

If I look at the disks there is no longer a drive at /dev/sdf but there is one at /dev/sdg.  I don't think I want to run the "replace" command mentioned in the status as my understanding that is destructive and will resliver the data onto sdg which I believe is the missing sdf.

How can I swap out sdg for sdf or cachieve something similar without destroying the pool data on sdg?

I looked around for information on this message but wasn't finding much useful or that I could understand.  I saw references to mdadm, but that does not seem to be my problem;

david@Media:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
unused devices:

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using generic SCSI /dev/sdX names for your ZFS pool devices because they can change across boots. I prefer using entries from /dev/disk/by-id

In this case, you can probably replace the missing disk with the new device location:

```
zpool replace data 10841317365380570418 sdg
```

Comment: Thanks.  As a beginner with ZFS, I was just following easy tutorials which don't always follow best practices.  I was wondering about the sdX names changing.  I did;

"zpool export [zpoolname]" then 
"zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id [zpoolname]"

which seems to have gotten the disk back in the pool and given me disk ids now in zpool status, but not sure if that will stick on reboot.

Comment: That works too!